# passing xml attributes to ant build.xml file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ant

I use Ant to build my swf output file.
I have got in project directory (along with project src/*.as files) build.xml, package.config and directory.properties files.
The package.config file is created outside by Nuget, so I need to rely on values in it:

```
<packages>
    <package id="Lib1" version="1.0" />
    <package id="Lib2" version="1.0" />
</packages>
```

now in build.xml I'm adding file:

```
<property file="package.config" />
```

then I need to include libraries (compiler.include-libraries) containing in their names package.id and package.version
i.e.:

```
<include name="package.id" + "package.version" + ".swc" />
```

Unfortunately I can not do it this way. I should probably store packages attributes somewhere and then use it passing to name property in  tag.
Thanks in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be using [xmlproperty task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) combined with [script task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) using builtin (since Java 1.6.0_06) javascript engine. 

Given xmlfile from Nuget :

```
<packages>
 <package id="Foo" version="1.0"/>
 <package id="Bar" version="1.0"/>
</packages>
```

Ant snippet using given xmlfile :

```
<project>

<xmlproperty file="yournugetfile.xml" collapseAttributes="true"/>

<!-- show properties from xmlpropertyfile -->
<echoproperties prefix="packages"/>

<!-- produce includes from those package properties -->
<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
 var pids = project.getProperty('packages.package.id').split(',');
 var pvers = project.getProperty('packages.package.version').split(',');
 var incl = "";
 for (i=0; i < pids.length; i++) {
  incl += pids[i] + pvers[i] + '.swc' + ',';
 }
 project.setProperty('cincludes', incl.substring(0, incl.length - 1));
]]>
</script>

<echo>$${cincludes} => ${cincludes}</echo>

<!-- demonstrate possible use -->
<echoxml>
 <compiler.library-path dir="some/path" append="true">
  <include name="${cincludes}"/>
 </compiler.library-path>
</echoxml>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Tue May 20 16:37:54 CEST 2014
[echoproperties] packages.package=,
[echoproperties] packages.package.id=Foo,Bar
[echoproperties] packages.package.version=1.0,1.0
[echo] ${cincludes} => Foo1.0.swc,Bar1.0.swc
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<compiler.library-path append="true" dir="some/path">
  <include name="Foo1.0.swc,Bar1.0.swc" />
</compiler.library-path>
```

Comment: Thanks for these tips. All I was needed was assigning my xml file as xmlproperty task. After minor modifications I managed to get my build working. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have the package attributes in a .properties file.  This will make your life easier with Ant, and won't require extra tools like [XMLtask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) to scoop them out of the XML document you mentioned.  Take a good read through [Ant's documentation about how properties work.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#properties)  Properties get expanded from references that look like ${this}, and you don't need to concatenate things with the + sign like you're trying to do.

You'll end up writing something that looks more like this:

`<include name="${package.id}${package.version}.swc"/>`

Comment: Yes, but I already have my directory.properties file which in I store other project props (mostly paths to other libs). I just needed the way to use my xml file as we like to distinct Nuget packages files there from other projects libraries. Kindest.